# Butterworth Filter attenuates noticeably in pass-band

Tags: low-pass, active-filter, bode-plot

**The Issue:**

I am using a Maxim MAX7480 8th order Butterworth low-pass filter to counter any aliasing from a sensor that measures signals up to 3kHz, but I only want up to 1kHz. Thus a critical frequency of 1kHz.

Datasheet: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7480.pdf

The problem is that while the critical frequency seems to work near perfectly, there is approximately 6-7dB attenuation across the entire passband, as shown in the image below.

Measurements are taken using a Digilent Analog Discovery 2, and the network analyser tool, generating a Bode plot.

[image: Bode plot of measured Butterworth filter response]

The attenuation can be seen between the yellow and blue lines in the left half of the upper diagram, where the vertical red line shows the value of the attenuation.

The passband response that is expected is shown below, in a diagram from the datasheet for this filter IC.

[image: Datasheet passband response.]

**Attempted Solutions:**

I have tried connecting the Analog Discovery to a standard RC filter, which results in the 6-7dB attenuation not being present; aka the blue line is shifted upwards and overlaps the yellow until close to the critical frequency. This would suggest that the error is not with the equipment.

One concern is that the wires the Analog Discovery uses are too long, and could be causing some issue. (Image of circuit at end of question.)

So far I have attempted two circuit configurations, one followed the recommended circuit setup from the datasheet, and connected COM and OS to ground via a 100n capacitor.

The other configuration connects COM and OS to VDD using a voltage divider, giving VDD/2. This was a recommendation listed above the "Typical Operating Characteristics" graphs in the datasheet.

Neither of these solutions have removed the 6-7dB attenuation.

I would be greatly appreciative of any ideas as to why this might be happening, or if I simply have to live with it and add some sort of gain after the fact.

[image: Circuit configurations]

**Images of the circuit:**

[image: Circuit]

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Couple of suggestions: try the offset adjustment circuit given in Fig.3 (don't forget the bypass caps).  Also, not sure what the Zin of the discovery is, but it seems like they were measuring with 10k || 50pF at the output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that the output is drawn to ground with 10k || 50pF when they were measuring?

Comment: Datasheet measurements always loaded **out** with 10k paralleled with 50 pf. You might try adding an opamp unity-gain buffer so as to present a high-impedance load to MAX7480 output.

Comment: Well, it doesn't mention the load in the section with graphs, but it does specify a load in the filter characteristics section.  That would be significant if the IC were driving say a 50 ohm load.  But, from what I can see the Discovery 2 is 1M ohm||24pF unless that changes in VNA mode?

Comment: Nicely phrased question. I don't have an answer -- and no time right now to invest in attempting one -- but your tools are good, the frequency range you are working with are compatible with using a breadboard... I can't explain the loss, just yet. But +1 for the question.

Comment: @glen_geek Aka attempt (independently) the 10k || 50pF on output, and the unity gain on output, measuring between the filter and || connection, and at the unity gain output?

Comment: @Buck8pe I'll give it a go with the recommended impedances I suppose. I haven't found anything stating a different impedance in the network mode after a short google.

Comment: @jonk Thanks, I appreciate it! I certainly wouldn't say no to other fine answers, so if you happen upon the subject later on the more the merrier :)